# Winstad Manor: Will my firepit go if I change my small house to an entryway?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

I just bought Hearthfire in Oldrim and was very keen to get going with building Windstad Manor. I should have focused on the main house construction rather than the furnishings and I put a firepit and cooking pot in the small house which will become the entrance.

Now I realise that when I extend the house I won't want this firepit there. When I convert this small house to an entryway, will the firepit/cooking pot disappear? I would prefer this. In the future I will just focus on construction of the main areas rather than any interior furnishings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The firepit will disappear. You will be able to construct a new (larger) cooking place with a hearth in the main house. In addition, you'll be able to construct (among others) a kitchen.

Most efficient/practical order is to finish construction of the entire house before starting on any furnishing.
**When the main house is constructed, there is no way back!**

Comment: Mixxiphoid, thanks for this. I note someone asked the same question in this thread https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/615803-the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim/63972769 and also the Wiki specifically says the firepit can be removed when you remodel, and it gives instructions on how to do so https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Small_House - it can apparently be done after the main hall is constructed. You are right, I should focus on construction FIRST before undertaking any kind of furnishing.